# Boole Algebra, ab+bc+ca=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a), how to solve starting from left?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was able to find a demonstration,
starting from the right part, 
I wanted to start from the left part, in order to check if I understood well my knowdlege,

Starting from left or right does make any difference in how it's complex the resolution? And, in case yes, what criteria should I use to identify which part is simpler?

My current steps are these:

(intuition, with the expanded form, I can have some chance to re-group as I need, I will add the missing term but with neutral values)

ab+bc+ca = ab(c+'c) + bc (a+'a) + ca (b+'b) 
................ = abc + ab'c + abc + 'abc + abc + a'bc 
................ = how should I proceed?

(the single quote is not)

The steps from the right are these:
(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = a(b+c)(c+a)+b(b+c)(c+a)
........................... = abc+aab+acc+aac+bbc+abb+bcc+abc 
........................... = abc+ab+ac+ac+bc+ab+bc 
........................... = abc+ab+ac+bc 
........................... = ab(c+1) + ac + bc 
........................... = ab+ac+bc

Following the suggestion in the comment, i.e. how's supposed to deduct that starting from ab+ac+bc, I should add ab(c+1)? The general intuition here is what's missing, thank you

Comment: Since this is an equality, just reverse the steps, read your proof from bottom to top.

Comment: @MasB True, but the reverse steps, seems very unnatural from the bottom (i.e. guessing I shoud add c+1? why?) , like suggesting there should be another way to solve it from the bottom. 
I miss the intuition in why I should have started right, basically.

Comment: Distribution works both ways, also over AND: $$ab+bc+ca = (a+bc+ca)(b+bc+ca)$$

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution works both ways, also over AND. To mimic your attempt from right to left:

$$\begin{align*}
ab+bc+ca &= (a+bc+ca)(b+bc+ca)\\
&= (a+b+c)(a+b+a)(a+c+c)(a+c+a)(b+b+c)(b+b+a)(b+c+c)(b+c+a)\\
&= (a+b+c)(a+b)(a+c)(a+c)(b+c)(a+b)(b+c)\\
&= (a+b+c)(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\\
&= (a+b+c0)(a+c)(b+c)\\
&= (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)
\end{align*}$$